# Is it possible to paginate put_item in boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

When I use boto3 I can paginate if I am making a query or scan

Is it possible to do the same with put_item?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you are trying to accomplish? What does pagination on a put request look like to you? Pagination generally refers to the results of a query, so it's unclear what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

The closest to "paginating" `PutItem` with boto3 is probably the included [`BatchWriter` class](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/a72c1583f8de58b40997433bc321fc47d2831b1c/boto3/dynamodb/table.py#L63) and associated context manager. This class handles buffering and sending items in batches. Aside from `PutItem`, it supports `DeleteItem` as well.

Here is an example of how to use it:

```py
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
table = dynamodb.Table("name")

with table.batch_writer() as batch_writer:
   for _ in range(1000):
        batch_writer.put_item(Item={"HashKey": "...",
                                    "Otherstuff": "..."})
```

Answer (score 1):

Paginating is when DynamoDB reaches its maximum of 1MB response size or it you are using `--limit`. It allows you to get the next "page" of data.

That does not make sense with a PutItem as you are simply putting a single item.

If what you mean is you want to put more than 1 item at a time, then use BatchWriteItem API where you can pass in a batch of up to 25 items.

You can also use high level interfaces like the batch_writer in boto3 where you can give it a list of items any size and it breaks the list into chunks of 25 for you and writes those batches while also handling any retry logic:

```
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
table = dynamodb.Table("name")

with table.batch_writer() as batch_writer:
   for _ in range(1000):
        batch_writer.put_item(Item=myitem)
```

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html#